# Array of proxies on a linux machine

Tags: linux, arrays, proxy, routes, ip

I would like to setup a system which I could change the ip any time I want.
The Idea I have is to have a list of proxies, which by pressing a button or something similar will switch to a different proxy server.

any suggestions of how to do it( I believe there is already a software for that somewhere)

I use ubuntu 10.04 (linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change network settings as normal luser, look for [Networkmanager](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/networkmanager).

For Firefox there are some extensions/add-ons that let you switch between proxy from a list, e.g. [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/2464/).